# Add forwarding address with service account from Gmail ruby API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, gmail-api

I try to setup a forwarding address to an accout with the Gmail API.

I'v authorized the API on my Gapps account, but I get the following error :

```
{
 "error": "unauthorized_client",
 "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
}
```

Here is a sample of my code :

```
scope = [Gmail::AUTH_GMAIL_SETTINGS_BASIC]
      attrs = {
         json_key_io: File.open('lib/google/client_secret.json', 'r'),
         scope: scope
       }
       auth = ::Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(attrs)
       impersonate_auth = auth.dup
       impersonate_auth.sub ='paul@myd.com'
       service = ::Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
       service.authorization = impersonate_auth
       service.create_user_setting_forwarding_address(ue.email, auto_forwarding_request)
```

Here is the permission for this service on my Gapps:

```
calendar 
email 
Email (Read/Write/Send)  https://mail.google.com/ 
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing 
profile
```

Comment: Did you follow the [mplementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) guide for implementing service accounts in Gmail API?

Comment: I'm getting the same response - "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method" - all of a sudden with the Gmail API. This is for code that has been working for years and for a G-Suite organisation that has our Marketplace app switched on for _all_ org users. I'm wondering if something is wrong on Google's side of the fence. Have you got anywhere?

Comment: Fixed for me, you should add ALL scopes presents on your request when you setup the delegation on Gapps